# Android: Notifications using a Service

Tags: android, service, notifications

I never worked with Services before. So, after following few demons on internet my implementation is this:

In my MainActivity's onResume() I am starting the Service this way:

```
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationsService.class));
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(this, NotificationsService.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0);
am.cancel(pi);
am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60000, 60000, pi);
}
```

And my NotificationsService Class is:

```
public class NotificationsService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        handleIntent(intent);
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
    private NotificationManager nm;
    private WakeLock mWakeLock;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mWakeLock.release();
    }

    private void showNotification() {

        nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
                "Notification Ticker", System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Intent i = new Intent(this, NotificationsActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("notification",
                "This is the Notification " + date);
        i.putExtra("notifiedby", "xyz");
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "xyz",
                "This is the Notification", contentIntent);
        nm.notify(R.string.service_started, notification);
    }

    private class PollTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            showNotification();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            stopSelf();
        }
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // obtain the wake lock
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                "NotificationsService");
        mWakeLock.acquire();
        // check the global background data setting
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (!cm.getBackgroundDataSetting()) {
            stopSelf();
            return;
        }
        new PollTask().execute();
    }
}
```

In the NotificationsActivity I am getting the Extras and showing the. These Extras have a time stamp and  I am calling the showNotifications() method once every minute (60000 ms).

**Problem:**

1. The time stamp I am showing in the NotificationsActivity, which I get from the Service Extras is the TimeStamp of the 1st Notification

E.g., if it's 10:10:10 A.M for the 1st notification it's been always 10:10:10 A.M in the Activity. But in the Notifications panel it's showing the updated one like 10:15:10 A.M for every Notification created every minute.

1. If I am setting the Notification every minute, I expect the Notifications to be separate. Instead it is just replacing the previous Notification. Or best would be like 10 Notifications from myApp.

How to get these?

**Mainly I want to know why the timestamp not getting updated?**

Comment: you can edit your question after you've posted and add such information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The time stamp i am showing in the NotificationsActivity, which i get from the Service Extras i the TimeStamp of the 1st Notification

If the activity was still running, it should be called with `onNewIntent()` instead of `onCreate()`, and the `Intent` delivered to `onNewIntent()` should have the appropriate extras. `getIntent()` always returns the `Intent` used to create the activity in the first place.

> If i am setting the Notification Every minute, I expect the Notifications to be separate.

Users think that developers who flood their screen with notifications to be complete imbeciles.

> Instead it is just replacing the previous Notification.

That is what you are telling it to do with your call to `notify()`.

Comment: For the last point. Should i change the ID in notify(). To show a new Notification without removing the previous one?